# How to access bpos Exchange online via WebDav?

Tags: webdav, exchange-server, mapi

I am trying to access my exchange mailbox via WebDav.
Locally I used the following URL to do so:

https://server/exchange/username/inbox/

Since we moved our server to bpos (exchange online) I am not sure which URL to use to access my mailbox. The bpos server does handle multiple domains and I am not sure where to put the domain in the url above.

Does anyone has some experience in accessing the bpos exchange server programmatically?

Thanks
   Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search and dozens of tests I seem to have found my problem:

First of all, WebDav does NOT work with Exchange Online. 
There is a solution using WebServices, that works quite nice.

I seem to have to set the Exchange Version to 2007_SP1. I did not find any option to leave this item blank or have it detected.

```
var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
// Just to get the trace messages
service.TraceEnabled = true;

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack; 
service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("<Username>", "<Password>");

// Autodiscover does NOT work if Exchange is not in the local net
// This is the url you have to use for german account (red002)
service.Url = new Uri("https://red002.mail.emea.microsoftonline.com/ews/Exchange.asmx");
```

What I still cannot understand is why you have to know the exchange version in advance, and have no option to negotiate that with a call.

Similar is the fact that I have to know the URL to be able to connect to the exchange server. Is it not the basic idea of the cloud to NOT have to know where your data is hosted?

I hope this code helps somebody. I sure would have needed this advice :-)

Answer (score 0):

We use "WebDAV .NET for Exchange", commercial library to access to Microsoft Exchange Online server over the WebDAV protocol. You have to use Forms Based Authentication to login and url is like https://red003.mail.microsoftonline.com/exchange/xxxxxx@xxxxx.microsoftonline.com

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

If I use the URL 

https://red002.mail.emea.microsoftonline.com/exchange/username@domain/

I always get redirected to the OWA site. 
Could you please show me how you access a folder and read the containing mails?